# custom ios keyboard invalidated/interrupted

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

Spent the whole day on searching information about these errors.
I'm going to create a keyboard with images and i'm using collectionView created in storyboards. Everything works OK in iPhone Simulator, but in real device debugger says that:

```
 2016-06-15 17:57:19.415 stickers[4627:59771] plugin home.testKeyboard.stickerKeyboard interrupted
    2016-06-15 17:57:19.417 stickers[4627:59771] plugin home.stickerKeyboard invalidated
    Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?